# jquery script working fine on chrome but not ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

My script seems to be working fine on firefox and chrome but it seems to fail on ie8. 
Stragely i placed an alert function right before all the code in the script and the alert function works. but the document.ready function almost never executes.
Is this an ie8 issue? if so then how can I work around this?
please help.

code:

```
<script src="/_layouts/topsoe.common/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js?rev=YoBy5yEtsejNrLIrIXUs2g%3D%3D" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // hide the last two columns and their headings
    $("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-vh2:eq(5)").css("display", "none"); // for the last two column headings;
    $("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-vh2:eq(4)").css("display", "none");
    // for each row in the application page
    var idcount = 0;
    $("#WebPartWPQ3 .ms-itmhover").each(function () {
        var proj_ID='project' + idcount; // assigning each row an id so that they can be accesed individually
        $(this).attr('id', 'project' + idcount); 
        idcount = idcount + 1;
        $("#"+proj_ID+"  .ms-vb2:eq(5)").css("display", "none");
        $("#"+proj_ID+" .ms-vb2:eq(4)").css("display", "none");
        // extracting the project status and the precentage of completion. these will be used to assign color codes
        var status = $("#"+proj_ID+" .ms-vb2:eq(3)").html();
        var percentage = $("#" + proj_ID + " .ms-vb2:eq(5) div").html();
        var suffix = percentage.match(/\d+/);
        console.log(proj_ID + "\n" + status + "\n" + percentage); // remove after testing
        // formatting the status cell accroding to the status and percentage;
        var bg_color; var status_formatted;
        if (status == "In Progress") {
            $("#" + proj_ID + " .ms-vb2:eq(3)").html("<div style='position:relative; width:" + suffix + "%;background:#44AFF6; z-index:0; height:60px; margin-bottom:-50px;'></div><div style='position:relative; z-index:1; text-align:center; margin-left:2px;' >In Progress</br>" + percentage + "</div>");
        }
        if (status == "Completed") {
            $("#" + proj_ID + " .ms-vb2:eq(3)").html("<div style='position:relative; width:100% ;background:#57C759; z-index:0; padding:20px 2px; coor:black; height:23px; text-align:center'>completed</div>");
        }
        if (status == "Halted") {
            $("#" + proj_ID + " .ms-vb2:eq(3)").html("<div style='position:relative; width:" + suffix + "%;background:#FF0033; z-index:0; height:60px; margin-bottom:-50px;'></div><div style='position:relative; z-index:1; text-align:center; margin-left:2px;' >Halted </br> " + percentage + "</div>");
        }
        if (status == "User Acceptance Testing") {
            $("#" + proj_ID + " .ms-vb2:eq(3)").html("<div style='position:relative; width:100% ;background:#FFFF66; z-index:0; padding:20px 2px; coor:black; height:23px; text-align:center;'>UAT</div>");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please check that, Which line of code throws the JS error in IE8? You can check it by using Script's console window of developer tool.

Comment: If I remember correctly your scripts will fail if you use console.log() on ie8

Comment: strangely there is no error. the code just stops working . Also I've noticed that it works after i have opened the console

Comment: "There's no error"??? You definitely get "`Cannot find property log of undefined`" in IE8 when having `console.log()`s in the code, and the console is not open, though you can't see that error in the console ; ).

Comment: if(!console) {console={}; console.log = function(){};}

Comment: Teemu@ when the console isn't running where will IE print that error message? Aren't  error messages supposed to be printed in the console?

Comment: You've something called "Statusbar" in IE8. You can see a small yellow triangle there when an error occurs. Doubleclick that triangle, and you'll see the error messages. Also there's an option in Internet Options to show error messages in separate window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced exactly the same situation once in my app. There were no errors but the code wont run unless u open the developer tools. And the culprit was that console.log statement. Comment/Remove that console.log statement and it should work fine

Comment: yeah!! IE is weird!! never faced this with other browseres

Comment: weird? Its f**** irritating. It nearly took my whole day to figure that out. And surprisingly, that console was only inside an initialize function of a backbone router that was misbehaving. Consoles in other parts of the code were working normally. Thats y most of us hate IE :P